# How to make last td of the row to highlight once a row is hovered just using css?

Tags: css

I want to highlight last cell of the row when it is hovered. Is it possible to do that with just css. Here is the link to work.

http://jsbin.com/isukemih/2/edit

I tried following ways

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}

tr:last-child:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to set to red the background color of the last cell of the hovered row :

```
tr:hover td:last-child {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/AnujUME/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tr:hover td:last-child {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many good options

```
tr:hover td:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
tr:hover td:last-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
tr:hover td:nth-last-child(1){
    background:red;
}
```